# run() method not running

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to make a simple space shooter game but it is not working well at the start. How it will be its end? Something is going wrong with my code. The overridden run() method of the Runnable interface is not working. Why the run method is not working as it should?  Moreover any information about how to shoot more independent bullets. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameWindow extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    static final int WIDTH = 500;
    static final int HEIGHT = 500;
    static final String title = "East Game Development";

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;

    GameWindow() {
        setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle(title);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private synchronized void start() {
        System.out.println("Debugging start method");
        if (running) {
            return;
        }
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread();
        thread.start();
    }

    private synchronized void stop() {
        if (!running) {
            return;
        }
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        System.exit(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Debugging");
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("Working well...");
        }
        stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameWindow gw = new GameWindow();
        gw.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think running variable should be volatile because Java caches the runnig variable value and when the stop method exams it in if clause the cached value will returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
thread = new Thread();
thread.start();
```

You're creating a thread without passing it anything to run. The Thread constructor expects a Runnable as argument, and this runnable is what will be executed in the thread. You thus want

```
thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
```

Note, though, that your code is not thread-safe: the run() method reads the value of the `running` variable without synchonization. And it might thus see it as true aven if the stop() method has been called in another thread. You should use the stanard interruption mechanism to ask your thread to stop, and to check if the thread must continue to run:

```
public void stop() {
    thread.interrupt();
}

public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a thread, you should specify which runnable instance it will call `run`. In your case:

```
thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
thread = new Thread();
```

You are creating normal Thread and starting it. Why do you expect your run()  method to run?

```
private synchronized void start() {
    System.out.println("Debugging start method");
    if (running) {
        return;
    }
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if u have only `JFrame` no really need to make it a runnable. just use these in main method:

```
gw.setVisible(true);
gw.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```